# Cascade delete not working as it should

Tags: django, django-models

If I was to delete a **Contact** object the related Unsubscribe object should cascade delete. It appears this is not the case, why? Is there anything wrong with the Contact model  seen below? Thank you.

**Unsubscribe**

```
class Unsubscribe(models.Model):
    """

    Notes:
    See: http://www.screamingatmyscreen.com/2012/6/django-and-generic-relations/
    """
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, help_text="Represents the name of the model")
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(help_text="stores the object id")
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    reason = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    request_made = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                   help_text="Shows when object was created.")
```

**Contact:**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, help_text="Shows when object was created.")

    objects = ContactManager()

    #FK
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='contacts', blank=True, null=True)
    contact_owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct `ForeignKey` relationship from `Contact` to `Unsubscribe`.

In the `Unsubscribe` model, there is a reference to `Contact` object by a generic relationship (This translates to just a database table entry that stores `object_id` and the `content_type_id` - not the actual foreign key reference ), hence the cascade delete does not work. One way you can delete the corresponding `Unsubscribe` object is, in a [`pre_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-delete) signal on the `Contact` object

Comment: If I did a pre_delete signal then I would have to state the relationship name defeating the point of it being generic, right? I don't want dependance. Is this even possible?

Comment: AFAIK, NO - for generic relationships

Comment: last question then, the pre_delete could go on contact, right?